# How to remove page number of PDF in UIWebview

Tags: swift, pdf, uiwebview

I'm currently embedding a PDF in a `UIWebview` using the following code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let lesson2_2 = "lesson2_2"
    if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: lesson2_2, withExtension: "pdf") {
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        webview.loadRequest(urlRequest as URLRequest)
        webview.scalesPageToFit = true
        webview.isOpaque = false
    }
}
```

The PDF shows up fine but displays the page number in a box in the top left. Is there any way that I can remove this number and have it hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo can try below code ,will hide page number view at top left:

```
 for subView: UIView in webView.subviews() {
        if (subView is UIScrollView) {
            for shadowView: UIView in subView.subviews() {
                if (shadowView is UIImageView) {
                    shadowView.isHidden = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
```